# ODBC in Excel with SSO/external authentication (OSX)

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have successfully set up and tested an ODBC connection on OSX to a Snowflake instance, using external SSO authentication. Testing was done using iODBC.

However, when I attempt to use the driver in MS Excel for OSX, at the authentication via external web browser stage, I am getting an 'Operation Not Permitted' error. Is it possible to use ODBC with external browser authentication within Excel?

Comment: Same issue here. Very disappointing.   I guess we'll just have to use Excel on a Windows VM or Remote Desktop. ‍♂️

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this error with Excel on Mac as well.  Last I heard, Microsoft Support determined that this functionality is not, and will not be supported in Excel for Mac. Feel free to open a ticket with Microsoft if you'd like to see this supported.